# My javascript seems to give an Uncaught RangeError and my text doesn't appear on screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I press the tab with the title "Brancusi" I get a "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error and my text doesn't appear. After that, on any other tab I press, I get the same error, but then at the third tab press it behaves normal again. Until I press on "Brancusi" again.
I've been told to use JSFiddle so here it is: [My code in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vladpaun1/Lf2eg9t1/).
I am quite new to web design so please explain everything to me like a baby.

Here is the code:

JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    let contactButton = document.querySelector('#contactButton');
    contactButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
      window.open("https://vladpaun1-congenial-goldfish-4xjp7gp49542jjp6-8080.preview.app.github.dev/personal/website_concurs/contact.html", "_blank");
    });

    var contentDiv = document.querySelector(".content");

    if (contentDiv) {
      var homeTab = document.getElementById("home-tab");
      var casaBrancusi = document.getElementById("casa_brancusi");
      var casaTopirceanu = document.getElementById("casa_topirceanu");
      var casaPann = document.getElementById("casa_pann");
      var brancusi = document.getElementById("brancusi");
      var topirceanu = document.getElementById("topirceanu");
      var pann = document.getElementById("pann");

      if (homeTab) {
        homeTab.addEventListener("click", function() {
          contentDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/backgrounds/BACKGROUND1.jpg')";
        });
      }

      if (casaBrancusi) {
        casaBrancusi.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          if (!event.handled) {
            event.handled = true;
            contentDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/casa_brancusi/casa_brancusi.jpg')";
          }
        });
      }

      if (casaTopirceanu) {
        casaTopirceanu.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          if (!event.handled) {
            event.handled = true;
            contentDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/casa_toparceanu/casa.jpg')";
          }
        });
      }

      if (casaPann) {
        casaPann.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          if (!event.handled) {
            event.handled = true;
            contentDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/casa_pann/casa.jpg')";
          }
        });
      }

      if (brancusi) {
        brancusi.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          if (!event.handled) {
            event.handled = true;
            contentDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/backgrounds/BACKGROUND1.jpg')";
          }
        });
      }

      if (topirceanu) {
        topirceanu.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          if (!event.handled) {
            event.handled = true;
            contentDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/toparceanu/toparceanu1.jpg')";
          }
        });
      }

      if (pann) {
        pann.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          if (!event.handled) {
            event.handled = true;
            contentDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/pann/pann1.jpeg')";
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

I tried handling misstriggers in my js code but that didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, in my HTML, for an  atribute i had the same href and id and changing the id seems to have fixed it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: you should put the relevant HTML in the question, then show how you fixed it in the answer.

Comment: The infinite recursion is happening in the `_activate()` function, which isn't in the question. You should add that to the question, and show how it's called. The question is missing anything relevant to the problem, so this is useless to future readers.